# Resources for pronouncing Latin

Tags: pronunciation, resource-request, study-strategies

What resources are out there for learning to pronounce Latin?
Latin was pronounced differently in different places and eras, so resources for any part of the spatiotemporal realm of Latin are welcome.
When you propose a resource, please explain what it contains (instructions, audio recordings, what kind of Latin, …) and if there are benefits and drawbacks one should know.

**Please give only one course per answer.**
If you have many courses to suggest, give multiple answers—but read the other answers to avoid duplicating answers.
This way people can vote on individual courses, causing the best ones to rise up and the worst ones to sink down, so that we can easily find the most useful resources.
If there are many courses listed in an answer, it's hard to link the answer score to the quality of each listed course.

> **Note about resource questions:**
>   Broad resource questions like this are generally **not** allowed on this site.
>   The community chooses a select few to avoid an overflow of questions of this kind.
>   If you have an opinion on what resource questions should be asked next, post a suggestion in [this meta post](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/188/79) or vote on the existing ones.
>   The ones to be asked will be chosen from that list according to their number of votes.
>   If you have ideas about listing resources on this site in general, you can contribute to [this meta discussion](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/177/79).
>
> In particular, if you would like to ask a similar resource request question, do **not** just ask it, but post a suggestion in the [mentioned meta post](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/188/79) instead.

Answer (score 11):

*Vox Latina* by W. Sidney Allen (2nd edition, 1978) is the standard book for pronouncing not just Classical Latin, but noted variants, as well. The book is a companion to *Vox Graeca,* and is a reconstruction of how it would be pronounced according to a variety of sources.

While it's a work of scholarship, it's easily accessible to undergraduates and other serious beginners.

Answer (score 9):

One resource for learning Latin pronunciation is [Nuntii Latini](http://areena.yle.fi/1-1931339), the Finnish Latin news broadcast.
The pronunciation is very clear and the news items are also available as plain text, making it easy compare the written and spoken word.
When the show is not on a winter or summer break, it produces 5 minutes of news every week.

It is not presented as study material, but it does fit in that role.
I enjoy the fact that it's not artificial stories for the sake of learning Latin, but actual news items simply delivered through the medium of Latin.
However, the words are not pronounced slowly and one at a time nor are there any pronunciation instructions.
But if you like learning by imitation, I recommend this as a part of your Latin hobby.

The Latin used there is the contemporary Latin pronunciation in Finland ([excluding Turku](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/562/79)).
I believe the pronunciation is supposed to follow classical pronunciation of the early Roman Empire.
I described this pronunciation in my answer to [a question on contemporary local Latin pronunciation](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1177/79).
And if you catch me speaking Latin in public, the accent will be very close to that of Nuntii Latini.

Answer (score 4):

For Ecclesiastical Latin, I am using audio published by Familiae Sancti Hieronomi, a religious community with a special charism for the Latin language:

http://www.hieronymus.us.com/Venalia/IndLatin.htm

My experience is with their Cursus and their recording of the book of Psalms.

These are specifically Ecclesiastical Latin materials, which is great if that is what you are looking for, so you get ecclesiastical pronunciation and texts.  Also, I find the pronunciation rather convincing.  (I can think of only one voice that has a rather thick American accent.)

The production quality will be lower than you expect: plan for some hiss and tracks at widely divergent volume levels.  Oh, and there is no way to sample the audio, it is on CD only, and they have no way to take credit cards!  Caveat emptor!

Comment: This looks like an interesting source. Do I understand the linked page correctly if I interpret that the audio has to be ordered on CDs and there are no free samples? It might be good to add such practical details in the answer.

Comment: Or, you know, go to a Catholic service in Latin and listen.

Comment: @OrangeDog, if you attend an extraordinary form mass, you will hear relatively little Latin for your efforts, as the priest is under no obligation to be heard and nearly half of the prayers are intentionally spoken in a low voice.  An ordinary form mass in Latin, if you can find it, will likely be said by a priest who has very little training in Latin.  I would still go, but not for the sake of hearing Latin.

Comment: All priests should have equivalent Latin training, and those that say Mass in Latin have the most practice. If you want to hear how Ecclesiastical Latin is spoken in your country, a Latin ordinary form Mass is the best place.

Comment: http://wheelockslatin.com/chapters/introduction/introduction.html

Answer (score 3):

Here's a new opportunity with regard to Ecclesiastical Latin.

On June 8, 2019, Vatican Radio started broadcasting *Hebdomada Papae, notitiae vaticanae latine redditae* (The Pope's week in review: Vatican news bulletin in Latin), a 5-minute weekly news bulletin airing every Saturday.

The programme is curated by Alessandro De Carolis, head of Vatican Radio, and results from the collaboration between Vatican Radio journalists and the Vatican Secretariat of Latin Letters, which already draws up official documents in Latin and manages the pope's Latin language Twitter account. [See here for more info.](https://www.vaticannews.va/en/vatican-city/news/2019-06/latin-news-vatican-radio-hebdomada-papae.html)

[On the English version](https://www.vaticannews.va/en/podcast/vatican-radio-news-in-latin.html) of the Vatican News website you can find all the broadcasts, and [on the Italian one](https://www.vaticannews.va/it/ricerca.html?q=Hebdomada%20Papae&in=all&sorting=latest) there are also transcriptions and translations in Italian. Note that as of now the Italian version of the website is the only one having these, they haven't been uploaded on the others (yet?).

Comment: It seems to me there are no more transcripts available, not even in Italian. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I added the link to all the podcasts in English and removed the transcript bit. Please revert change if needed.

Comment: @luchonacho: Fortunately there still are! Thank you, I guess it wasn't clear enough, I improved the wording on the basis of your edit.

Comment: added a new answer, in case you are interested

Comment: @luchonacho: Nice!

Answer (score 2):

Another resource for Ecclesiastical Latin. Every day the [Vatican Radio](https://www.vaticannews.va) transmits some of the "hours" of the [Divine Office](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liturgy_of_the_Hours) (also called Liturgy of the Hours) in Latin. These are the Lauds, Vespers, Compline (there is also the Rosary in Latin). These are Catholic prayers but might be helpful for learning because of two reasons:

1. The prayers, psalms and readings **vary every day**
2. The Latin texts and English translations of each prayer are **freely available** in many places online. My favourite is [this one](https://universalis.com/) (available also as a [paid] smartphone app). To use, select one of the "hours", and select Latin and English at the end. Example for Lauds [here](https://universalis.com/L/0/lauds.htm).